# how to set a default value in ng-options AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I would like to set a default value to my select component using angular `ng-options`
I have seen other topics about this question but i try to use it in my case but not solve.. 
So i have a select component

```
<select ng-options="dis.entidade.idEntidade as dis.entidade.nome for dis in distritos" ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
    <option></option>   
</select>
```

and i would like to set a defaul value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to set at `no-model` property. Example:

```
$scope.distrito.entidade.idEntidade = $scope.distritos[0].entidade.idEntidade;
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('select', function($scope) {
  $scope.distrito = {};
  $scope.distrito.entidade = {};

  $scope.distritos = [{
    entidade: {
      nome: 'test1',
      idEntidade: 1
    }
  }, {
    entidade: {
      nome: 'test2',
      idEntidade: 2
    }
  }];

  $scope.distrito.entidade.idEntidade = $scope.distritos[0].entidade.idEntidade;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="select">
  <select ng-options="dis.entidade.idEntidade as dis.entidade.nome for dis in distritos" ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
 
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can set `$scope.distrito.entidade.idEntidade = "defaultValue"`. Your ng-model is the selected value, so if you don't initialize it in your controller, the value will be undefined. **If you set a value to the relevant model during initialization, this will be the default selected value.**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.somethingList = [];
  $scope.somethingList.push("Something1");
  $scope.somethingList.push("Something2");
  $scope.somethingList.push("Something3");
  
  $scope.selectedSomething = $scope.somethingList[0];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-options="something for something in somethingList" ng-model="selectedSomething"></select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-options="dis.entidade.idEntidade as dis.entidade.nome for dis in distritos" ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
<option>THIS IS YOUR DEFAULT VALUE</option>
```

If you want to have a default value with some meaning you should do it in your controller, eg:

```
if (!$scope.distrito.entidade.idEntidade)
  $scope.distrito.entidade.idEntidade = 'Some default value';
```